# Gradle build failing in offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to android studio, when I enable Gradle offline mode
it reports *"sync failed No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1 available for offline mode."*
this have baffled me for a week wish someone could solve this for me

Answer (score 1):

Basically your Gradle is offline so it won't attempt to consult the network to download any dependencies that aremt already in its cache.

1. Please [disable Gradle offline](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#offline_mode) mode.

   Open the Preferences window by clicking <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Settings</kbd> (on Mac, <kbd>Android Studio</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>).

   In the left pane, click **Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle**.

   Check the **Offline work** checkbox.

   Click **Apply** or **OK**.

   OR

   If you're building from the command line, pass the `--offline` option.
2. Rebuild the Project.
3. Then re-enable Gradle offline mode again (if that's what you want).